# How to validate html files during pull request in azure devops?

Tags: html, azure, github, azure-devops, azure-marketplace

I have a repository that has only HTML files. Is there any extension in the marketplace or any other way to validate if the files have the correct syntax during the pull request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML Validate](https://html-validate.org/usage/cli.html) seems like a nice command line tool to validate documents for proper HTML. Install it and use it in a bash task from your pipeline.